# Why will with code not let me in even though I have the right password?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a password and username sign in thingy. I have made OOP (object oriented programming) to make this, but it will not give me the correct result.

More info in the code.

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self, uid, password):
        self.uid = "admin"
        self.password = "admin"

    def authenticate(self):
        if self.uid == logid and self.password == logpass:
            print("Login successful")
        else:
            print("Sorry, that was incorrect.")

login = Login("carolynlikesmath", "pass")
logid = input("Enter your user ID: ")
logpass = input("Enter your password: ")

login.authenticate()
```

Comment: Is the password supposed to be "admin", or "pass"?

Comment: You are doing `self.uid = "admin"`, so whatever you are passing to `Login()` is being _ignored_ and the `uid` in the class is set to `"uid"`.

Answer (score 0):

you need to pass your variables to class

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self, uid, password):
        self.uid = "admin"
        self.password = "admin"

    def authenticate(self,logid ,logpass):
        if self.uid == logid and self.password == logpass:
            print("Login successful")
        else:
            print("Sorry, that was incorrect.")

login = Login("carolynlikesmath", "pass")
logid = input("Enter your user ID: ")
logpass = input("Enter your password: ")

login.authenticate(logid ,logpass )
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `__init__` method is *ignoring* the `uid`/`password` being passed to it.  It's just setting `self.uid` and `self.password` both to "admin" regardless of what you are passing when creating a `Login()` object.

If you want "default" values for those parameters, set them in the method signature itself.

Also, `authenticate()` has no idea about the `logid`/`logpass` variables.  Those are outside of the class.  You need to pass them to `authenticate()` to be verified.

```
class Login:
    def __init__(self, uid="admin", password="admin"):
        self.uid = uid
        self.password = password

    def authenticate(self, logid, logpass):
        if self.uid == logid and self.password == logpass:
            print("Login successful")
        else:
            print("Sorry, that was incorrect.")

login = Login("carolynlikesmath", "pass")

logid = input("Enter your user ID: ")
logpass = input("Enter your password: ")

login.authenticate(logid, logpass)
```